# Can we configure single OAuth2 client with multiple Resource Server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have deployed 3 different applications(Resource Server) in my environment and one of my clients need to access all the three applications. What is an ideal way to do? Should I register my client to each Resource Server separately or Should I register the same Client with all the Resource Server?

If I register separately then I need to maintain three ClientId and Secret and but for the second case I just need one client credential.

What is the ideal way of handling such situation? Is there any OAuth standard where they have maintained all these details?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Resource Servers all are associated with the same Authorization Server you should register one Client with that Authorization Server.

If the Resource Servers are all part of the same security domain (i.e. operated by the same party) then a single access token suffices to access all 3 Resource Servers.

If somehow the Resource Servers are controlled by different parties and you want to avoid leaking access tokens between them, then you should use 1 access token per Resource Server, associate different scopes to each of these Resource Servers and have your Client ask for a particular one via the "scope" request parameter.